# Output of Python Code

Tags: python, input, python-3.x

I am new at python. Here is my wiered python code Which works fine for all inputs except

when c=0 and r!=0 .

I have number of test case(tc) , r and c as inputs which give required output depending condition.

Question---For input r=4 & c=0  ,Output Should be 2,but output is coming  1 .  I am geting wrong answer for every r!=0 & c=0.

Code:

```
tc=int(input())
while tc:
     r,c=raw_input().split()
     if int(r)%2==0 and r!=2 and r!=0 and c!=0:
        r=int(r)/2
     elif r!=2 and r!=0 and c!=0:
        r=int(r)/2+1
     elif r==0 or r ==2:
        r=1
     if r!=0:
        if int(c)!=0:
           print(int(r)*int(c))
        else :
           if int(r)%2==0 :
              print(int(r)/2)
            else:
               r=int(r)/2+1
               print(r) 
     else :
        print(c);
     tc=tc-1
```

sample input and output

```
4         //tc
10 10     //r=10 c= 10
50        //fine
3 3       //r=3 c=3
6         //fine
4 0        //r=4 c=0
1         //Should be 2 accoring to code
5 0      //r=5 c=0
2       //Output should be 3 accoring to the code
```

Comment: What is the code supposed to do?

Comment: Please fix your indentation.  We can't tell where the `while` loop ends.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You have solved the mystery yourself (kind of):

```
if int(r)%2==0 and r!=2 and r!=0 and c!=0:
```

`r` is a string. So `r` will always be `!=2` because `"2" != 2` is always true. Same goes for all the other comparisons.

I'm guessing you first got a `TypeError` with `if r%2==0`, so you changed that bit of the program (also in all the other places where you're actually doing calculations with the values) but neglected to apply this insight to the other parts of the program.

So first convert all your inputs to `int`s, then start applying your program logic.

Comment: Check for the output r=100 and c =0 ,It is giving 25 instead of 50

Comment: Ok Sir,Thank you very much it is wroking when I convert r and c to int at the begining.